# How do I search in Firebase Database

Tags: c#, firebase, search, firebase-realtime-database

How do I search for a user in unity using Firebase Database without using Elastic Search?

So I found this [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b_tz8kbFUsU) which helped me out on Android Studio And I would like to know how can I replicate this for Unity?

(My Terrible Attempt)

```
public void SearchUser()
{
    FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference.Child("user_id").OrderByChild("username").StartAt(searchField.text).EndAt(searchField.text + "\uf8ff")
          .GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
    if (task.IsFaulted) {
      // Handle the error...
    }
    else if (task.IsCompleted) {
      DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
                  // Do something with snapshot...
                  Debug.Log("Found " +snapshot.Value.ToString());
    }
  });

}
```

Comment: What does your Firebase DB look like?

Comment: `users > userid(key) >                                                                                        
        -user_id : (key)                                                                                          
        -username : john smith`

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert but I have been following this documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/retrieve-data)

```
FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
    .GetReference("users").OrderByChild("username").EqualTo(searchusername)
    .ValueChanged += HandleValueChanged;
}

void HandleValueChanged(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs args) {
  if (args.DatabaseError != null) {
    Debug.LogError(args.DatabaseError.Message);
    return;
  }
  // Do something with the data in args.Snapshot
}
```

I think you need `EqualTo(searchusername)` somewhere.

Comment: EqualTo() method requires me to type in the users full username, what I'm trying to do is use "StartAt(searchField.text).EndAt(searchField.text + "\uf8ff")" so I can partially type in the users username to find him instead of typing his whole username. I will try and use the .ValueChanged function tomorrow since its rather late at the moment and I do not have my IDE and Unity open. I'll keep you posted.